# Dataframe change names of factors if frequency of the factor is lower than some number

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column of factors and a column of numerics, like below.

```
x <- data.frame(c("Cat", "Dog", "Cat",
                  "Elephant", "Cat", "Zebra",
                  "Cow", "Cow", "Sheep"),
                 c(12, 5, 19, 6, 1, 20, 3, 11, 4))
colnames(x) <- c("animals", "number")
```

I want to change this data frame so that if the frequency of animals in my "animals" column is less than 2, the names of animals are changed to "others", so that it would look like below:

```
data.frame(c("Cat", "Other", "Cat",
            "Other", "Cat", "Other",
              "Cow", "Cow", "Other"),
                c(12, 5, 19, 6, 1, 20, 3, 11, 4))
```

I've identified how to figure out which columns have frequency lower than 2 by using the code below, but can't figure out how to change the name of variables associated with those numbers. Any comment would be appreciated!

```
x.count <- count(x, "animals")
which(x.count$freq < 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- 2
x %>% 
  group_by(animals) %>% 
  mutate(animals1 = as.character(animals), animals1 = ifelse(n() < n,
          "Other", animals1)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(animals = animals1, number)
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#  animals number
#  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 Cat         12
#2 Other        5
#3 Cat         19
#4 Other        6
#5 Cat          1
#6 Other       20
#7 Cow          3
#8 Cow         11
#9 Other        4
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
i1 <- with(x, ave(seq_along(animals), animals, FUN = length) < n)
levels(x$animals) <- c(levels(x$animals), "Other")
x$animals[i1] <- "Other"
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting solutions in both `tidyverse` and `base R`, this is exactly what I was trying to get done. I've never used `tidyverse` before but thanks for introducing how to use it!